# Spring-WS project creation

Tags: java, spring, spring-ws, spring-tool-suite

I'm trying to develop a simple starter project on Spring-WS using STS 3.9.
I'm new to this technology I'm done with theoretical concepts of web services and Spring-WS.
I have also gone through the spring.io official website for project creation but things over there were not very clear to me.

Can anyone please share some links that shows step by step development of project creation.

Also i also want to know apart from STS spring framework jars what all jars file are required for the same project.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend to take a look at the guides at https://spring.io/guides/. They provide simple-to-follow guides for a wide variety of topics around Spring, including web services. Not sure exactly what kind of web service you are looking for (RESTful or SOAP, whereas RESTful services are the preferred way nowadays), but you will find guides for both.

In case you found a guide that helps you, you can import the guides directly into a workspace in STS via the "Import Spring Getting Started Content" wizard, which you can find via the "New -> Other" and search for "Spring".